# Which database design scales better?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, scale

Which would scale better for recording votes and subscriptions of a question?

**A.** 2 tables, 1 for each **subscriptions** and **votes**, each with foreign keys to join **questions**, in which case I'd query with a union of 2 queries to each table to get all the activity for the question.

**OR**

**B.** 1 table with 1 foreign key to join to **questions** and a field to record if the row is a **vote** or **subscription**. In this case there will be an extra join condition for some of my other queries too.

Comment: do subscriptions and votes have the same metadata? will they always?

Comment: scales for what? reading? writing?

Comment: @Jeff Lauder votes table != subscriptions table

Comment: then you should use two tables

Comment: @Marc B How would each perform reading and writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about 'scaling', you have to be more precise on *what* operations you want to scale?* Do you need to optimise read, write, both? file dumps? fetch external content?

Once you know **what** you want to scale, often you'll also need or want to figure out **how much** you want to scale to, and *if your tweaks offer any benefit at all*,  by benchmarking and profiling.

This is fun, depending on the context. Benchmarking on a saturday night is not allright.

Some of the database optimising techniques I am aware of involve denormalisation and such tricks that you don't see much in ordinary environnments, so using those "hacks" for better performance sometimes (often) bring a price on code maintainability for example. In the case of denormalisation technique I mention above,  you lose some of the data-integrity your  database offers *and then have to implement it in your application code*.

Not so good for the developper,  he has to replicate a DB's data integrity just to have a faster database query time. In light of the above, friend it is my humble opinion (being a lazy developer), many scaling problems can be avoided *by disregarding scaling problems in the first place*, until they occur.

If you want to talk of standard, good db building practices, from a general sql  perspective, I only know of the 2 main ways, the normalised way and the non normalised way. Both have sub-variants but I guess that would look like your A, and your B. Both are valid options, and both have pros and cons, but if your application is not to be flooded by thousands of hits a minute I would say use A, maybe something similar to this:

`Table votes`         - has primary key vid,

`Table questions`     - has primary key

`Table subscriptions` - has primary sid, foreign key vid, qid

Good-luck, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

In general a `JOIN` is going to be more expensive than a `WHERE` clause on a single table, so if your sole consideration is scaling a large data set, I would go with option B.  That said, probably more important than simple scaling is proper data design, and unless you can guarantee that votes and subscriptions will remain essentially the same (which is rare), you're better off with A.  For example, if at some point you want to add a point value to the vote (not just yes/no), then two tables are immediately more appropriate.